# Is it acceptable for Muslims to donate to Christian charities?

Tags: christianity, sadaqah

The other day I donated to a Christian "get kids off drugs" charity.  The Quran says to do good deeds, and the charity seemed consistent with Muslim values, so when they asked for a donation, I obliged.

**Question**: Is it acceptable for Muslims to donate to Christian charities?

Maybe I'm overthinking this.  I don't view Christians as adversaries, but I wonder if it's inappropriate to donate to Christian charities, who may go on to use the money to teach about Jesus in ways that are inconsistent with the Quran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no nothing (That I came across of know of) in the Quran and Sunnah any thing that limits Kind treatment and charity to Muslims only, All verses that speak of charity and good act do not only limit these interactions to a single specific group. Some of these verses are quoted below:

> Allaah does not forbid you to deal justly and kindly with those who
>   fought not against you on account of religion nor drove you out of
>   your homes. Verily, Allaah loves those who deal with equity”
>   [al-Mumtahanah 60:8]

In Surat Al Insan, as shown in the verses quoted below, yet again God does not specify who charity is given to:

> They [are those who] fulfill [their] vows and fear a Day whose evil
>   will be widespread. 76:7 And they give food in spite of love for it to
>   the needy, the orphan, and the captive 76:8 [Saying], "We feed you
>   only for the countenance of Allah . We wish not from you reward or
>   gratitude. 76:9

Yet again in Surat An-Nahl:

> Surely Allah enjoins the doing of justice and the doing of good (to
>   others) and the giving to the kindred, and He forbids indecency and
>   evil and rebellion; He admonishes you that you may be mindful(16:90)

And also in Surat Al Baqara:

> Righteousness is not that you turn your faces toward the east or the
>   west, but [true] righteousness is [in] one who believes in Allah , the
>   Last Day, the angels, the Book, and the prophets and gives wealth, in
>   spite of love for it, to relatives, orphans, the needy, the traveler,
>   those who ask [for help], and for freeing slaves; [and who]
>   establishes prayer and gives zakah; [those who] fulfill their promise
>   when they promise; and [those who] are patient in poverty and hardship
>   and during battle. Those are the ones who have been true, and it is
>   those who are the righteous. 2:177

Unfortunately many Muslims have become closed minded, as they have created a division between them and other nations this could be due to many causes such as nationalism or viewing their culture OR tribe as superior, this has an influence on the way they think and put forth opinions, however this is against what God instructs us in the Quran:

> O mankind! We created you from a single (pair) of a male and a female,
>   and made you”INTO NATIONS AND TRIBES” that ye may know each other (not
>   that ye may despise (each other). Verily the most honoured of you in
>   the sight of Allah is (he who is) the ”MOST RIGHTEOUS OF YOU” . And
>   Allah has full knowledge and is well acquainted (with all things).
>   [49:13]

Our religion does not demand its followers to be blind, be careful of where you receive knowledge and answers from, always verify what you have been taught with its source:

> "And follow not that whereof you have no knowledge. Surely, the
>   hearing, the sight, the heart--all of those shall be questioned
>   of."Al-Quran 17:36
>
> If you do not have complete knowledge about anything, better keep your
>   mouth shut. You might think that speaking about something without full
>   knowledge is a trivial matter. But it might have grave consequences
>   [24/15-16]

Coming to the last part of your question,if you know that your charity , you shouldn't give blindly, investigate to see what cause you are aiding then give if it is a righteous cause:

> Help you one another in Al-Birr and At-Taqwa (virtue, righteousness
>   and piety); but do not help one another in sin and transgression
>   [al-Maa’idah 5:2]

Although the charity was christian, its cause was still a righteous cause, so as long as you know that you donations are going to fulfil that cause then there should be no issue, but if it is to fund-raise missionary campaigns and things of that nature then this is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Those to whom it is acceptable to donate are prescribed in ([9:60](http://legacy.quran.com/9/60)).  So you there find those people who have been described as

> ...for bringing hearts together [for Islam] ... [Sahih international]
>   or
>   ...and for to attract the hearts of those who have been inclined (towards Islam) ... [Muhsin Khan]

That means you can donate to non-Muslims if they are supposed to support or convert to Islam in 1st place. Or if by this you may win them for Islam.

This doesn't seem to cover what you are intending in your Question!

On the other hand I think that Christians who are teaching about Jesus are not of that kind scholars would say it is acceptable to donate to them.

Comment: -1 for lack of resources, how is the OP supposed to know whether what you've put forth is an opinion or that which is truthful and has legitimate source?