# Is it permissible to donate money/clothes/food etc to Non-Muslims?

Tags: non-muslim, food, zakat, money, sadaqah

Salaam, my question is that "Is one allowed to make any types of donations to non-Muslims in need. Not as in sending Zakat, Sadaqah or Lillah - but just generally?"

Jazakallah Khair in advance

Comment: It is recommended to help anyone in need regardless of his/her faith. When Imam Ali (a.s.) was the kalif of the Muslim ummah, he saw an old man begging on the streets of Kufa. He became very upset about the fact that someone in his capital was in need to beg. He asked the people who he was , they replied that he was a Christian with whom in the past they did business with. Ali ibn Abi Talib ordered the people to take him of the streets, to give him a house and monthly payment from the treasury. He said, once you did business with him and now that he is old and weak you abandon him.

Comment: Zakat is mandatory, sadaqah or what you call lillah is optional and these cover all possibilities. And yes it is permissible...

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [Is it acceptable for Muslims to donate to Christian charities?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/33620/17163)